# Export org-mode blocks to a text file

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-babel

Is there a way to export the contents of org-mode [blocks](https://orgmode.org/manual/Structure-Templates.html) to a text file? The blocks will contain only ascii text.

I can export the contents of a source block using [Babel](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/intro.html) with tangling:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC  latex :tangle yes
Export this text to a text file.
#+END_SRC
```

However, this produces a file of type specified by the [language](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/index.html) identifier. The language identifier in the example above is `latex` and therefore the output is a .latex file. Is there a way to export a block to a .txt file?

**Update:**

matteol's solution works. However, the output file will be named out.text. It seems Babel takes the suffix from the language identifier in the header, so replacing `text` with `txt` will produce out.txt.

If you want to send the output to a .txt file with the same filename as the source org file, here is a working example:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC txt :tangle yes
Export this text to a .txt file.
#+END_SRC
```

For example if your source file is named my_document.org, the tangled output file will be named my_document.txt.

Because it is possible to export text in the way described, it might be helpful to update the [Babel language documentation](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/index.html) to reflect this. I don't see an option for txt in list of supported languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a file name in the `:tangle` header argument like this

```
#+BEGIN_SRC text :tangle out.txt
Export this text to a text file.
#+END_SRC
```

See [the manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Extracting-Source-Code.html) for details